# Div container to overflow out the body to edges of page

Tags: css

On my [Website Homepage](http://www.institute101.com) I inserted a grey strip container containing social network links. I want it to go all the way to the edges of the page like my footer.

This is the code I used;

```
  .outer {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin-left: -178px;
  padding-right: 349px;
  position: relative;
  }
```

I know it's an amateur attempt, can someone show me a better way to code this? At the moment when zooming out it detaches from the edges of the page.

Comment: show html as well, too difficult to understand your problem

Comment: Sorry not to mention it's a wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

Will need to see the html also

Maybe try taking away the margin if that div isn't contained by another one

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your site, and I'm not so sure the problem is with the CSS that you've printed out for us.

Your social networks strip is inside a section tag with class ".wrapper" which is set to width 1640px, and the strip is adjusting to the width of that wrapper.  Is there a reason you've set that ".wrapper" class so wide?

Your footer, on the other hand, is not inside that same "section.wrapper" element, so it is adjusting to the width of the browser.

Comment: It looks fine until you zoom out a few times causing it to detached from the edges of the page, unlike the footer. Also currently in mobile devices it is causing the sidescroll. I made the wrapper 1640px because the client wanted only 3cm's white gap from both sides on a 1080p resolution monitor with 100% zoom.